# How can I view/debug postgres database connections for Django app on Heroku?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

My Django app running on Heroku is currently crashing with a `Too many connections for role "my_user"` error and I need to figure out what's happening. I'm using the basic version of postgress on heroku that provides 20 connections.

The specific line of code causing the error, per my error page, is:

```
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect
...
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
...
```

I have a job that runs every 60 seconds as follows. Could this be creating a new connection each time it runs and leaving its prior connection open? I suspect not since this job ran for several hour without maxing out connections.

Clock.py file (runs every 60 seconds to send any queued mail):

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'anonqaproject.settings'

from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from post_office import utils

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(minutes=1)
def timed_job():
    utils.send_queued_mail()

sched.start()

while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out with some help from the postgres manager at Heroku. What I needed was:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Once I saw the `backend_start` and `query_start` datetimestamps for each connection it was obvious it was my scheduled job opening a new connection each time it runs - every 60s. Now I have to figure out how to make it reuse connections and/or close connections when it's done.

Comment: It turns out Django 1.6.1 does not automatically close db connections after running management commands. So I added `from django import db` and `db.close_connection()` to my pseudo cron job and now connections are no longer piling up.